# What are default keras layer weights

Tags: classification, deep-learning, keras

I build a classification model on keras (Vanilla MLP),It went quite well by using a tutorial.But what are the default weights of layers because I didn't mention any in the code.It has a feature of intializing weights, but what if we don't initialize.

Answer (score 2):

It uses [Xavier initialization](http://deepdish.io/2015/02/24/network-initialization/). If you don't initialize it, by default it uses this method for initialization. If you want to know how to perform that you can use [here](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/03/29/understanding-xavier-initialization-in-deep-neural-networks/). In the first link at the end, link of the paper is also available.

*This Xavier initialization (after Glorot’s first name) is a neat trick that works well in practice. However, along came rectified linear units (ReLU), a non-linearity that is scale-invariant around 0 and does not saturate at large input values. This seemingly solved both of the problems the sigmoid function had.*